# Cookies and cache, how to clean them from command line on Linux and Mac?

Tags: unix, caching, cookies, browser, command-line

For Chrome and Mozilla, mainly,

is there a way to clear the cookies and the cache from command line on Mac and Linux?

When I'm developping, frequently I have to clear the cache and cookies, I would like a simply or automatic way to do this.

Someone can help?

Answer (score 1):

I would write a simply perl script that would just delete all of the files from dirtecty x and y which would indicate where the cookis are located.

```
use strict;
my $deletedir = '/tmp/test1';
my $result = system("rm -rf $deletedir");
print "Result: $result\n";
```

Comment: Looks like a good idea. But clean cookies/cache is same as delete a folder content? If yes, the only thing I need is find the Chrome and Firefox directories^^

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do this inside the browser (file changes can't be reliable unless the browser is not running). No need for special software, just a separate browser profile and the standard "clear my data" menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to clear cookies and cache data from the command line for **Firefox** on the **Mac**:

```
#!/bin/bash
# A script to clear out Firefox data from the command line.
# MIT License <http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT>

src="$HOME/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles"

declare -a files_to_delete=(places.sqlite places.sqlite-shm places.sqlite-wal downloads.sqlite formhistory.sqlite search-metadata.json search.json search.sqlite cookies.sqlite cookies.sqlite-shm cookies.sqlite-wal signons.sqlite sessionstore.bak sessionstore.js)

declare -a directories_to_delete=(Cache OfflineCache)

# enable for loops over items with spaces
IFS=$'\n'

# loop through browser profiles and delete certain files
for dir in `ls "$src/"`
do
    if [ -d "$src/$dir" ]; then
        for item in "${files_to_delete[@]}"
        do
            if [ -f "$src/$dir/$item" ]; then
                rm "$src/$dir/$item"
                echo "deleting: $src/$dir/$item"
            fi
        done
        for item in "${directories_to_delete[@]}"
        do
            if [ -d "$src/$dir/$item" ]; then
                rm -r "$src/$dir/$item"
                echo "deleting: $src/$dir/$item"
            fi
        done
    fi
done
```

*Note: as this script uses the `$HOME` variable for the source (`src`) directory for where your Firefox Profiles directory resides, make sure to run this script as the user who owns the Firefox Profiles directory... **(i.e. don't run this script as root...)***

*Also note: it may be a good idea to **back up** your existing Firefox profile before running this script!*